# Setting WooCommerce Subscription status on renewal based on payment method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

With WooCommerce Subscriptions I want when you renew an order and subscription with cash on delivery (cod) the subscription status should change to on-hold until order is completed. Before a renew subscription order is paid, its status is 'pending' and when paid 'processed'

The current code I have on 'woocommerce_thankyou' only works on new subscriptions but not on renewed ones. 
I have tried 'woocommerce_order_status_changed' as seen below, but does not work.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'change_order_status_conditionally', 10, 4 );
function change_order_status_conditionally( $order_id, $status_from, $status_to, $order ) {
    if( $order->get_payment_method() === 'stripe' ) {
      $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    } else if($order->get_payment_method() === 'cod' && $status_to === 'processing') {
      if( wcs_order_contains_subscription( $order )) {
        // Get an array of WC_Subscription objects
        $subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order( $order_id );
        foreach( $subscriptions as $subscription_id => $subscription ){
            // Change the status of the WC_Subscription object
            $subscription->update_status( 'on-hold' );
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Any idea how I can fix this?